# Derivation of equation of the force required to pull the Magdeburg hemispheres apart

Tags: pressure

This is the equation of the force required to pull the [Magdeburg hemispheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magdeburg_hemispheres) apart:

$$F=\pi R^2 \Delta P$$

How this equation is derived?

Comment: Do you know what $\Delta P$ _ and the word _pressure_ mean_? Have you checked that the units are the same on both sides of the equation?  What are your remaining concerns?

Comment: Hi Achmed. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, $F$ is the sum of the pressure force on a hemisphere. You can find it by integrating on the hemisphere the small radial pressure forces.

$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{F} &= \iint\limits_{hemisphere}\delta \mathbf{F} \\
&= \iint \Delta P \delta S \hat{\mathbf{u}}_{\textrm{ext}} \\
&= \Delta P \int\limits_{\theta=0}^{\pi/2}\int\limits_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}
R^2 \sin(\theta)\textrm{d}\theta\textrm{d}\phi\ \hat{\mathbf{u}}_{\textrm{ext}} \\
&= R^2\Delta P\int\limits_{\theta=0}^{\pi/2}\int\limits_{\phi=0}^{2\pi} \sin(\theta)\textrm{d}\theta\textrm{d}\phi\hat{\mathbf{u}}_{\textrm{ext}}\ 
\end{align}
$$

Let's call $\hat{\mathbf{u}}_{x}$ the axis $\{\phi=0\}$, we know that $\mathbf{F} = F\hat{\mathbf{u}}_x$, so

$$\begin{align}
F &= \mathbf{F}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{u}}_x \\
  &= R^2\Delta P \int\limits_{\theta=0}^{\pi/2}\int\limits_{\phi=0}^{2\pi} \sin(\theta)\sin(\theta)\textrm{d}\theta\textrm{d}\phi \\
  &= \pi R^2\Delta P
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

I'll go through intuitively why that equation makes sense.

Imagine the hemispheres.  Together they obviously make a sphere.

No consider that $P = \frac{Force}{Area}$.

If the pressure is the same on the inside and outside, it does not require any force to move the spheres, because the net force due to pressure is equal on both sides.  As the pressure difference increases so does the force required to move them.

Now, imagine you are trying to separate the spheres into the left and right directions.  The only force we need to apply is the force to overcome the pressure in the left-right directions.  All the forces on the top/bottom and front/back sides are all balanced by each other, so they do not contribute to the resisting of the pulling.

Because of these balances, you can easily see the only force due to pressure will act in the direction we are pulling.

This means that the area the pressure acts on is the same as a side view (2D) of the sphere, which is the same as a circle with the same radius of the sphere.  Since pressure is proportional to area, to find the required force we need the area of the circle times the pressure difference, so $A = \pi R^2$ and $F = \Delta P \pi R^2$

Essentially, since pressure acts normal to the surface, to separate the spheres is essentially to move a flat surface of the same projected area (as long as we can ignore ignore forces like drag and other secondary effects).